# Reduce openstreetmap graph size in networkx

Tags: graph, openstreetmap, networkx

I have a graph (transformed from OSMNX) of London's walk path, containing 667.588 edges, with different `highway` attributes (the street types in openstreetmap). Running a shortest_path algorithm is quite slow (4 seconds). To improve the speed, I want to largely reduce the number of edges in a systematic way without losing main connections/city structures, but not sure how to do it? Any suggestions? Is there a way to group some close nodes to a more important one, thus reduce the size?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is somewhat broad. SO users can help you mostly when you are stuck with a specific kind of code or problem rather than suggest a general methodology. What are the different kinds of highway attributes you are having. Would it be an idea to filter out those that might be less important?

Comment: Mainly residential footpath and etc. I am looking for a method to group some nodes and cut out the nodes with only one edges.

Comment: Can you just use 1-2 highway categories? I suspect you only want "footpath" is that right? As for the nodes with only one edge, you can delete nodes with degree one

Comment: Maybe use a tool that is faster ;) - what exactly are you trying to solve so that 4 seconds is not sufficient?

Answer (score 3):

You can extract edges with desired highway types from your main graph `G`:

```
highways_to_keep = ['motorway', 'trunk', 'primary']
H = nx.MultiDiGraph()
for u,v,attr in G.edges(data=True):
    if attr['highway'] in highways_to_keep:
        H.add_edge(u,v,attr_dict=attr)
        H.node[u] = G.node[u]
        H.node[v] = G.node[v]
```

Here, we first initialized an empty `MultiDiGraph`, which is a type of graph used by `OSMnx`, then populate it with data from the main graph `G`, if the `'highway'` attribute is in our list of `highways_to_keep`. You can find more about highway types in [this](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway) OpenStreetMap page.

Our graph is a valid NetworkX graph, but you need to do one more thing before you can take advantage of OSMnx functionalities as well. if you execute `G.graph`, you will see graph attributes which contains `crs` (coordinate reference system) and some other things. you should add this information into your newly create graph:

```
H.graph = G.graph
```

here is the plot of `H` , `osmnx.plot_graph(H)`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I want to use walk maps which means the majority of them are residential roads (No motorways). Should I only keep residential street? They are still quite a lot.

Comment: In that case it is best to solely rely on 'walk' network type provided by OSMnx. My guess is that the 4 seconds you mentioned in your question is not for computing shortest path from one node to another, it is probably for one node to all other nodes or even every node to every other node. For that, 4 second it totally fine. if you do not supply any argument (e.g. nx.shortest_path(G)), it will compute shortest path between every pair of nodes. nx.shortest_path(G,node1) computes shortest paths between node1 and all other nodes, and nx.shortest_path(G,node1, node2), only between node1 and node2.

Comment: Did my comment helped you? You don't have to, but it is a good manner to respond to people who spend their time helping out, or accept the answer/up-vote if the answer is what you were looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I was away the weekend. I do look for one to one pair. The 4 seconds is using nx.shortest_path(G,node1, node2, 'length'). This is because of the large number of edges. Your solutions is good, but it may cause some disconnection in the graph, and when you down the similar to the network (I am doing it on a walking network in London), the number of edges is very close to 'Drive' network. But thanks a lot!

Comment: I was also thinking to get the edge number reduced by group some nodes according their importance.

Comment: It is usually faster to use A* algorithm, but the problem is you cannot use it on MultiDiGraph (i.e. OSMnx graphs) because it is not implemented in networkx. One work around would be to convert MultiDiGraph to simple weighted Graph and average edges' weights where we have multiple edges between two nodes ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590812/networkx-convert-multigraph-into-simple-graph-with-weighted-edges)).

Comment: Can we convert it into a DiGraph or just weighted Graph? A DiGraph would be more useable. Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be possible. A* doesn't accept Multi(Di)Graph (see [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/_modules/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/astar.html)), but it works with DiGraph. `G.selfloop_edges()` and `G.nodes_with_selfloops()` gives you self-loops in the Graph. The difference between DiGraph and MultiDiGraph is these self-loops, so merging them together should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I am not working on this currently, but will try while I got time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of network you're working with (e.g., walk, bike, drive, drive_service, all, etc.). The `drive` network type would be the smallest and prioritize major routes, but at the expense of pedestrian paths and passageways.

OSMnx also provides the ability to [simplify the graph's topology](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.simplify.simplify_graph) with a built-in function. This is worth doing if you haven't already as it can reduce graph size by 90% sometimes while correctly retaining all intersection and dead-end nodes, as well as edge geometries, faithfully.

Comment: I directly create the graph form 'London, UK'. So it seems the network has been simplified and cannot be done again.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution does not work anymore since the networkx library has changed. Specifically

```
H.node[u] = G.node[u]
```

is not supported anymore. 
The following solution relies on the osmnx.geo_utils.induce_subgraph and used a node list as an argument to this function.

```
highways_to_keep = ['motorway', 'trunk', 'primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary']
H = nx.MultiDiGraph() # new graph
Hlist = [] # node list
for u,v,attr in G.edges(data=True):
    if "highway" in attr.keys():
        if attr['highway'] in highways_to_keep : 
            Hlist.append(G.nodes[u]['osmid'])
H = ox.geo_utils.induce_subgraph(G, Hlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

The osmnx simplification module worked for me in this case https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.simplification:

> **osmnx.simplification module**
>
> Simplify, correct, and consolidate network topology.
>
> ```
> osmnx.simplification.consolidate_intersections(G, tolerance=10, rebuild_graph=True, dead_ends=False, reconnect_edges=True)
> ```
>
> Consolidate intersections comprising clusters of nearby nodes.
>
> ```
> osmnx.simplification.simplify_graph(G, strict=True, remove_rings=True)
> ```
>
> Simplify a graph’s topology by removing interstitial nodes.