# NetworkX compute clustering of MultDiGraph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

In order to compute the clustering of a MultDiGraph , I first convert the MultDiGraph into directed graph. Then when I try to compute the clustering I get this error message.

```
NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for multigraph type
```

Is there any way to calculate the clustering of the MultDiGraph?

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to transform your multidigraph into a weighted digraph, as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590812/networkx-convert-multigraph-into-simple-graph-with-weighted-edges). Assuming your multidigraph is unweighted:

```
import networkx as nx
# MultiGraph
M = nx.MultiDiGraph()
M.add_edge(1,2)
M.add_edge(1,2)
M.add_edge(2,3)
M.add_edge(1,3)
M.add_edge(1,4)

# create weighted graph from M
G = nx.DiGraph()
for u,v in M.edges():
    if G.has_edge(u,v):
        G[u][v]['weight'] += 1
    else:
        G.add_edge(u, v, weight=1)

clustering = nx.clustering(G,weight='weight')
clustering
```

Note this requires NetworkX 2.2.