# networkx change weighted directed graph to undirected

Tags: python, graph, networkx, data-mining

Is a built-in function in networkx could change weighted directed graph to undirected? The functionality should change two directed edges (n1,n2,5) and (n2,n1,7) to one (n1,n2,12).

I searched a long time and didn't fund out one.

Comment: If you check the documentation you can find `to_undirected()`. But this still don't solve the sum of the arcs I think.

Comment: Yes I checked this function while didn't find built-in function in networkx to solve the problem.

Comment: [This solution may be what you are looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590812/networkx-convert-multigraph-into-simple-graph-with-weighted-edges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networkx has a [to_undirected](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.to_undirected.html#networkx.DiGraph.to_undirected) function but it doesn't sum weights, it is just updating weight with the last found edge weight from the original graph:

> If edges in both directions (u, v) and (v, u) exist in the graph, attributes for the new undirected edge will be a combination of the attributes of the directed edges. The edge data is updated in the (arbitrary) order that the edges are encountered. For more customized control of the edge attributes use add_edge().

You should do it manually like this:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([
    (1,2,3),
    (1,3,4),
    (2,1,5),
    (2,3,1),
    (3,2,2)
])
UG = G.to_undirected()
for node in G:
    for ngbr in nx.neighbors(G, node):
        if node in nx.neighbors(G, ngbr):
            UG.edges[node, ngbr]['weight'] = (
                G.edges[node, ngbr]['weight'] + G.edges[ngbr, node]['weight']
            )
UG.edges.data('weight')
```

will return summarized weights:

`EdgeDataView([(1, 2, 8), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 3)])`