# Networkx Net Edges

Tags: python, networkx

I have a file with edges that are duplicated for a good reason.

The duplication is bi-directional, meaning I have A->B multiple times, but also B->A, multiple times.

I need to **net the edges**, meaning add all A->B and subtract all B->A. The result of which should be either a A->B or B->A edge with positive values as in A->B negative should be B->A.

I started with this script (found here [Networkx : Convert multigraph into simple graph with weighted edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590812/networkx-convert-multigraph-into-simple-graph-with-weighted-edges)) and it performs well the sums of all A->B, **but** it also sums B->A to A->B edges, when I'd need it to subtract.

**Initial Code**

```
import networkx as nx
# weighted MultiGraph
M = nx.MultiGraph()
M.add_edge(1,2,weight=7)
M.add_edge(1,2,weight=19)
M.add_edge(2,3,weight=42)

# create weighted graph from M
G = nx.Graph()
for u,v,data in M.edges(data=True):
    w = data['weight'] if 'weight' in data else 1.0
    if G.has_edge(u,v):
        G[u][v]['weight'] += w
    else:
        G.add_edge(u, v, weight=w)

print(G.edges(data=True))
# [(1, 2, {'weight': 26}), (2, 3, {'weight': 42})]
```

**Then I add a B->A edge**

```
#trying to subtract from 1->2 edge above
M.add_edge(2,1,weight=26)

#reprocess entire calculations
G = nx.Graph()
for u,v,data in M.edges(data=True):
    w = data['weight'] if 'weight' in data else 1.0
    if G.has_edge(u,v):
        G[u][v]['weight'] += w
    else:
        G.add_edge(u, v, weight=w)

print(G.edges(data=True))
#results shows edge above added 26, not subtracted
#[(1, 2, {'weight': 52}), (2, 3, {'weight': 42})]
```

Comment: If you want the code to work, then you should change```M.add_edge(2,1,weight=26)``` to ```M.add_edge(2,1,weight=-26)```
Otherwise you need to modify the code by inserting an if-else statement. If the edge is a type A->B then```G[u][v]['weight'] += w```, else ```G[u][v]['weight'] -= w```.

Comment: Are your node labels of numeric type? Following your toy example you could do something like ```w = w if u < v else -w```

Comment: It looks to me like your final graph `G` should be directed, not undirected.  Because if it's an undirected graph, then it can't tell the difference between an `A` to `B` edge and a `B` to `A` edge.