# Pandas Edgelist to NetworkX weight aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Dears,

I have the following edgelist in pandasdataframe (with ~ 4 million rows, showing only a depiction of the issue):

| Customer_A | Customer_B | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | Customer 2 | 320 |
| Customer 1 | Customer 3 | 400 |
| Custmoer 2 | Customer 1 | 100 |

As you can see there is a two way connection between Customer 1 and Customer 2 and  when I create the networkx graph through :

`G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Customer_A', 'Customer_B', 'Weight')`

networkx takes only one of the two weights (my guess is the first one it encounters) and disregards the other one.
My question is how can I actually get to a graph which has the sum of the two weights (connection between Customer 1 and Customer 2 to be with a weight of 420 in this case).

I tried creating a adjancency matrix with a pivot on the dataframe but I am running out of memory considering the 4 million rows.

I am considering splitting into two graphs - one where only two way relationships exists and one where there are only one way but I don't thinkt his will solve my issue.

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Hristo

Comment: Does `G` end up being a graph, DAG, or multigraph? In other words, the return type of `nx.from_pandas_edgelist()`?

Comment: A workaround I am trying to implement is self joining the dataframe (left_on = ['CUSTOMER_A', 'Customer_B'], right_on = ['Customer_B','Customer_A']) then summing the weights and producing a graph based on the new weight, not sure how consistent this would be ;)

Comment: @riskRewarded graph, not a DiGraph or multigraph. I dont care (at least on this step) for directions.

Comment: Do multiple Customer 1 -> Customer 2 edges have their weights combined by `nx.from_pandas_edgelist()`?

Comment: @riskRewarded I am not sure, I have a single Customer1-> Customer2 and single Customer2->Customer1 I would guess it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an undirected MultiGraph it will allow multiple edges between nodes, where the edges between any two nodes are undirected and their weights can be summed. I then think you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590812/networkx-convert-multigraph-into-simple-graph-with-weighted-edges#15598279) to collapse the MultiGraph down to a regular graph, combining weights for edge pairs.

```py
 M = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Customer_A', 'Customer_B', 'Weight', create_using=nx.MultiGraph)
```

Then use the accepted answer in the linked SO discussion to reduce the graph or, as suggested by the other answer, use a pre-processing answer that operates on the dataframe prior to creating the graph.

Comment: Thanks riskRewarded, will test out and let you know.

Comment: Had a chance to test for you, updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're better off doing preprocessing in Pandas - what you call "workaround". As far as I know there's no straightforward tool/method in NetworkX for this kind of transformations. (But, of course, that doesn't mean there isn't any!). The solutions in NetworkX that I'm aware of all include iterating over edges. The best would be to test the performance of both ways on a reasonable sized sample.

Two ideas for a "workaround":

```
df = df.groupby(
         df[['Customer_A', 'Customer_B']].apply(
             lambda row: '|'.join(sorted(row)),
             axis='columns'
         )
     ).sum().reset_index(drop=False).rename(columns={'index': 'Edges'})
df[['Customer_A', 'Customer_B']] = df.Edges.str.split('|', expand=True)
df.drop(columns=['Edges'], inplace=True)
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Customer_A', 'Customer_B', 'Weight')
```

or

```
df = df.groupby(
         df[['Customer_A', 'Customer_B']].apply(
             lambda row: tuple(sorted(row)),
             axis='columns'
         )
     ).sum().reset_index(drop=False).rename(columns={'index': 'Edges'})
df[['Customer_A', 'Customer_B']] = pd.DataFrame(df.Edges.to_list())
df.drop(columns=['Edges'], inplace=True)
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Customer_A', 'Customer_B', 'Weight')
```

Comment: Thanks Timus, ended up doing the workaround, although in a much cruder way than yours, will test out both ways you propsoe and provide feedback